# Doctrine select one to one bidirectional

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have these two classes:

```
Class Account {

/* @var customer
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="account")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $customer;
}

Class Customer{

/**
     * @var account
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Account", mappedBy="customer")
     */
    private $account;

}
```

And a query:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM SbCoreBundle:Customer c LEFT JOIN c.account a WHERE a.id = :user_id');
$query->setParameter('user_id', $id);
return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

What is wrong with my relationship and query? I get error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c0_.account_id' in 'field list'","errors":null}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you updated / created your database?

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Is field account_id in database?